# How can I enable custom exporter via OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER environment variable

Tags: open-telemetry, otel, open-telemetry-java

I intend to implement a custom span exporter in open-telemetry-java SDK, for this purpose I have written a class extending interface SpanExporter.

I am running an instrumented Java application which is auto-instrumented using open-telemetry-java SDK instrumentation library jar, I am able to build my custom jar with my custom SpanExporter and successfully run it. I attach my SpanExporter to TraceSDK using AutoConfigurationCustomizerProvider, but I do not want to hardcode it and set it directly via the environment variable `OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You have different choices - I wasn't sure which one you're looking for:

- You can implement a [ConfigurableSpanExporterProvider](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure-spi/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/autoconfigure/spi/traces/ConfigurableSpanExporterProvider.java) to be able to activate the exporter with `OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER` as explained [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/examples/extension#extensions-examples)
- If you want to add behavior to an existing exporter (typically `otlp`), you can [configure a tracer provider](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/src/main/java/com/example/javaagent/DemoAutoConfigurationCustomizerProvider.java#L39-L47)